# How to get background image centered in CSS

Tags: css

For some odd reason I cant get this background image to be centered. Its only centered when the page is at `50%` size.
On one of my other pages it works fine, however here it does not.

current HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>
        Why are you here?
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Akari.css">
</head>

<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1>
                <span class="colorYellow">Akari </span><span class="colorGreen">- Playstation</span><span class="colorAqua"> 3 VSH Menu</span>
            </h1>

        </div>
        <div class="body">
            <p>
                This is the page for Akari! Akari is a WIP VSH Menu for <span class="CEX">CEX</span>/<span class="DEX">DEX</span> CFW/<span class="henpt1">PS3</span><span class="henpt2">HEN</span></p> 
               
            <a
                href="https://github.com/JamesIsWack/Akari-Legacy-Edition/releases/download/v1.2.2-1/Akari.sprx">Click
                here to download the latest release (v1.2.2-1)
            </a>
            <p>
                <style>
                    p
                        {
                            color:rgb(194, 194, 194);
                    }
                </style>
                To install it, put the Akari.sprx into dev_hdd0/plugins, then add /dev_hdd0/plugins/Akari.sprx to boot_plugins.txt (COBRA), or mamba_plugins.txt (MAMBA)
            </p>
        </div>
        <p class="main">
            Screenshots
        </p>
        <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JamesIsWack/Akari-Legacy-Edition/main/images/160284617-befda427-14ca-463e-9e0f-4ab0ba59707f.png" width="400"></img>
        <p>Menu layout</p>
        <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JamesIsWack/Akari-Legacy-Edition/main/images/160284724-191861c3-29e9-4a31-ba99-6e157dc83240.png" width="400"></img>
        <p>Menu Settings</p>
        <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JamesIsWack/Akari-Legacy-Edition/main/images/160466345-e4620c97-8dec-43ce-8689-09f05189fa98.png" width="400">
        <p>Overlay and Settings</p>
        <u1>Features</u1>
        <li>
            Ability to restart VSH, Hardware
        </li>
        <li>
            Ability to show current FW version, LV2 Kernal mode (CEX/DEX)
        </li>
        <li>
            Can be loaded by COBRA, MAMBA, and PS3HEN
        </li>
        <li>
            Can take screenshots (BMP, PNG coming soon!)
        </li>
        <li>
            Overlay with FPS, CELL/RSX tempature (F/C), FAN speed, RAM usage, and more
        </li>
        <br>
        <p>
            Note: this project has been depricated. Please wait until Akari v2 releases. Until then, use this.
        </p>
        <br>
        <p> </p>
    </body>


    <div class="navbar">
        <a href="../index.html">
            Back to home
        </a>
    </div>
</html>
```

Current CSS:

```
body
        {
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0;
            background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            background-image: url(../images/channels4_banner.jpg);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            color: white;
           
        }
        a:link
        {
            color: rgb(126, 70, 156);
            text-decoration: none
 
        }
     a:visited
        {
            color: rgb(126, 70, 156);
        }
     a:hover
        {
            color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        }
     a:active
        {
            color: purple;
        }

    .navbar
        {
            background-color: rgb(52, 51, 51);
            overflow: hidden;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            border-radius: 10px;
            opacity: 90%;
        }
    .navbar a 
        {
            float: left;
            display: block;
            color: rgb(96, 46, 122);
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 17px;
        }
    .navbar a:hover 
        {
            background-color: grey;
            color: rgb(55, 37, 58);
            transition: background-color 1s,
                color 1s
        }
    .navbar a.active
        {
            color: white;
        }

h1 
            {
              background-color:  rgb(46, 31, 56);
              opacity: 90%;
            }
.colorYellow
            {
                color:yellow;
                opacity: 100%
            }
.colorGreen
            {
                color:greenyellow
            }
.colorAqua
            {
                color:aqua;
            }


main
            {
              color:rgb(195, 195, 195);  
              text-align: middle;
            }
    .CEX
            {
                color:lightskyblue;
            }
    .DEX
            {
                color:darkred
            }
    .henpt1
            {
                color:grey;
            }
    .henpt2
            {
                color:darkgoldenrod;
            }
```

[what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3WWv.png)

[what its supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRp8i.png)

I have tried changing the `background-size` but it hasnt gone anywhere.

Comment: You have 13 serious HTML errors as reported by the validator. Fix those first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This css code will get you a perfect full-page centerered background no matter the size.

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: tysm this worked!

Comment: No browser has needed those vendor prefixes in many years. In addition, you have ignored the many HTML errors he has.

Comment: @kernaltrap make sure to mark this question as answered for other people with the same problem! Glad to help!